# PUT request causing logout in Rails app with Devise and CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise, cancan

I've been searching for an answer to this the past couple of days. I'm trying to test my rails apps API with [POSTman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en). Right now I can do a GET request no problem. For example I can go to `vitogo.org/users/:id.json` and get a nice printout of the JSON for the user.

The problem is if I try to update the name of my user for example by doing a PUT request, the user session is destroyed and nothing happens. I tried disabling the CSRF token requirement for JSON requests, but that didn't solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we see some code? Can you duplicate this in a smaller app?

Comment: Sure. I just wasn't sure what code would be helpful. I haven't tried a smaller app yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer here was that I was sending the wrong JSON. With POSTman I was just giving a `key value pair`, when I need to do `model[key]:value`. so in my situation, to update my name in the user model, I needed to do:

`key: user[name] value: Dave.`

The above example would change my name from Arel to Dave. What it did was change the JSON being sent from `{"name"=>"Dave", "id"=>"39"}` which is wrong, to `{"user"=>{"name"=>"Dave", "id"=>"39"}}`